# How can I retrieve source codes from deployed one?

Tags: meteor

I made an app on Meteor and deployed it on Meteor's free server a year ago.
Then I lost my source code in my local machine by accident.

How can I get my source code from the server?

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to get your code back that easily since when you deploy it its bundled and minified. You can give it a shot at un-minifying your code/tidying it but you're going to be missing the server side code anyway.

Your best bet would be to contact the guys who make meteor & ask them for help very nicely: http://www.meteor.com/contact

Comment: I contacted Meteor and they kindly helped me.